# matlab cell array manipulation

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I create a cell with

```
s = cell(4,4);
```

now I want to edit two entries:

```
s{1,1:2} = ?? //what do I write here?
```

I've tried the following things:
    s{1,1:2} = {A,B};
    s{1,1:2} = {A;B};
    s{1,1:2} = {{A},{B}};
But none of them works.

It always says: 'The right hand side of this assignment has too few values to satisfy the left hand side.'

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
s(1,1:2) = {A,B};
```

Examples:

```
>> s(1,1:3) = {'first','second','third'}

s = 

    'first'    'second'    'third'     []
         []          []         []     []
         []          []         []     []
         []          []         []     []


>> A=12

A =

    12

>> B=4

B =

     4

>> s(1,1:2) = {A,B}

s = 

    [12]    [4]    'third'     []
      []     []         []     []
      []     []         []     []
      []     []         []     []
```